# Different look and feel for gnome classic in Debian 7 and Debian 8

Tags: debian, gnome-classic

I have upgraded a Debian 7 system to Debian 8 and, among other changes, when I log in using gnome-classic, the desktop background is new. However, my gnome menus have not changed, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

So, I have performed a fresh installation of Debian 8, and on that I get the following look and feel when I log in as gnome-classic:

[image]

Why are the icons, the menu look and feel, and the upper tool bar different?

Can it be that some packages have not been upgraded properly when going from Debian 7 to Debian 8?

If this is the case, is it possible to restore the look and feel of the upper picture in Debian 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure that this is the answer you are asking for, but if want the look and feel of the "classic" gnome 2, you can install and use the [MATE Desktop Environment](http://www.mate-desktop.org/) (`sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment`)!

i would definitely advise you to use MATE instead of the old gnome3 classic-mode:

1. MATE will use less resources
2. the so called "classic-mode" of gnome 3, is just a fallback-mode if your system faces problems with the graphic card
3. the classic-mode was discontinued as of gnome 3.6
   and debian squeeze (2.30+7), wheezy (3.4+7+deb7u1) or jessie (3.14+3) uses different versions of `gnome` by default!

Comment: It could surely help. I basically would like to keep the wheezy - gnome-classic look and feel.

Comment: i'm not sure what's your goal... for the look it is irrelevant what system (wheezy/jessie, ubuntu, fedora,...) you use; it only depends on your desktop environment! -- if you like the look of gnome 3 install the latest gnome and you are fine... if you want back the look of the old gnome 2 install and use the now called MATE!

Comment: forget the so called "classic-mode" of gnome 3, it's just a fallback-mode if your system faces problems with the graphic card!

Comment: The gnome-classic was close enough to what I liked in wheezy, but apparently this has been changed in jessie. Many thanks, I will try out mate.

Comment: Anyway, what you see above is the following. The upper screenshot is from a wheezy system that's been upgraded to jessie. This is what I see when I log in using gnome-classic, and the look and feel was fine to me. The lower screenshot is from a newly installed jessie system. Again, this is what I see when I log in using gnome-classic. My goal was to have the upper look and feel (wheezy + gnome-classic) in jessie. But I will try out mate too.

Comment: maybe this is interesting for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/65087/354350

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he want it because new Gnome in Debian 8 doesn't support 2D video cards any more (2005 Sis agp video card for example found in laptops). So he need old gnome to see a good image. On Sis agp video card Debian 8 it seems it lack's driver support so use some "new" driver that is no good at all. And is not only with Sis, Ati and Nvidia too !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I would like to keep the look and feel when switching to a new version. In any case, I do not want to be forced to adopt a new look and feel, I would like to choose between keeping the old one and switching to a new one. The possibility to choose has always been one reason I use Linux. So I do not see why it should be difficult to keep the old desktop alongside the new ones.